# Ember.js Router: Embedded resources

Tags: ember.js, router

I'm creating an Ember application to display twitter feeds but I am having trouble with displaying individual tweets through embedded resources.

The code is as follows:

## Templates

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tweets">
        <div id="stream">
            {{#each tweet in controller}}
                <div class="tweet">
                    <p class="tweet_text">{{tweet.text}}</p>
                    <p> {{#linkTo "tweet" tweet}} {{tweet.id}} {{/linkTo}}</p>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tweet">
        <div id="detail">
            {{text}}
        </div>
    </script>
```

## Router

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('tweets',function(){
        this.resource('tweet',{path: ':tweet_id'})
    });
});

// (1)  App.Router.map(function(){
//        this.resource('tweets')
//        this.resource('tweet',{path: ':tweet_id'})
//      });



App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('tweets');
  }
});

App.TweetsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    var me = [];
    $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=emberjs&rpp=200&count=200&callback=?", 
      {},
      function (data) {
        $.each(data.results,function(k,tweet){
             var tweet = App.Tweet.create({
                created_at: tweet.created_at,
                from_user: tweet.from_user,
                profile_image_url: tweet.profile_image_url,
                text: tweet.text,
                id: tweet.id
             });
             me.pushObject( tweet );
        });
    });
    return me;
  }
});
```

## Objects & Controllers

```
App.TweetsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});

App.Tweet = Ember.Object.extend({
  created_at: "",
  from_user: "",
  profile_image_url: "",
  text: "",
  id: 0
})
```

As you can see, I have a commented our router (1) which works in finding the correct tweet, and rendering it in the tweet template.  However, I would like this route to be nested so that I can implement it as a Master-Detail application.

Using the LOG_TRANSITIONS, I can see that the correct routes are initialised, but I cannot get the nested resource path to render.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. For anyone stuck on something similar, this is how I did it:

## Templates - Changed the {{#linkTo}} "tweet"... to {{#linkTo}} "tweets.tweet"... AND added an {{outlet}}

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tweets">
    <div id="stream">
        {{#each tweet in controller}}
            <div class="tweet">
                <p class="tweet_text">{{tweet.text}}</p>
                <p> {{#linkTo "tweets.tweet" tweet}} {{tweet.id}} {{/linkTo}}</p>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{ outlet }}
</script>
```

## Router - Changed 'this.resource' to 'this.route'

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('tweets',function(){
        this.route('tweet',{path: ':tweet_id'})
    });
});
```

## Caveat

I think this is a workaround and that the nested resource was the correct approach in this context.  I understand that a nested route should be "a verb" or action route. I would still be grateful if anyone knows the correct approach to the question but hope the above helps others where relevant.

Comment: It does not work if you use this.resource with this fixes? The only mistakes i could spot, were these you already fixed in your template.

Comment: no, if i change just the router to read 'resource'instead of 'route' I get "Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The route tweets.tweet was not found", so i change the link in my {{linkTo}} back to just 'tweet' and I don't get errors, but I dont get a rendered template either. If feels like such a small thing but I just cant pin it down.

Comment: Just read the guide http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/ again. I think the name of the nested resource route should be just tweet. When you nest it as a resource, it does not seem to inherit the name prefix from the parent route. So try {{#linkTo 'tweet' tweet}} plz :-)

Comment: Yeah, thats what I did above when I was saying that I changed the {{linkTo}} back to just 'tweet' when I changed the route map back to a nested resource.  Appreciate your suggestion though :)

Comment: Ok, did not get that. Maybe you need an index template in this case? I would try an tweet.index route and template?

Comment: Tried tweet.index...still no luck :(

Comment: And you changed the template name accordingly?